# foreach (HtmlElement elem in elemColl)Memory management with MSHTML dll

Tags: com

How do I free up memory for the objects of MSHTML Object library.
For eg. if I have HtmlTableClass in my windows application then how do I free up the object or dispose the object.

```
    foreach (HtmlElement elem in elemColl)
                {               
                    if (elem.TagName == "TABLE")
                    {
                        if (((mshtml.HTMLTableClass)(elem.DomElement)).className != null)
                        {
                            if (((mshtml.HTMLTableClass)(elem.DomElement)).className.ToLower() == className)
```

I have used the instance of  HTMLTableClass class. How do I free up the resource?

Comment: What language? If .NET, you don't have to do much, but you can show some code if you need more advice.

Comment: You are using a .NET wrapper for a COM object.  They get garbage collected like any .NET object, releasing the native COM object when that happens.  Using GC.Collect() is the unwise way to force that to happen early.  Whenever you think you need that, running a memory profiler to see what's going on is always the correct thing to do.

Comment: You mean I dont need to do any Disposing of the objects?

Answer (score 0):

There is no release function available to delete the object so it happens by itself.